# Getting / Setting static members of a template struct during runtime

Tags: c++, templates, static

I am trying to store information about a class with a template struct with static members during runtime, however I cannot get or set the static member without an error.

Why doesn't this code work?

```
template <typename T>
struct InfoHolder
{
    static const char* name;    
};

int main()
{
    InfoHolder<int>::name = "This is an integer";
    cout << InfoHolder<int>::name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a linker error. You have to define the `name` variable somewhere. (declaring it in a class doesn't allocate it anywhere, cause it is not part of an object)

write this after the class and before main:

```
template <typename T>
const char *InfoHolder<T>::name;
```

It is a small inconvenience of static data members.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this being used elsewhere;

Since the static member in the struct isn't allocated, I can use a static member from a function, and return a pointer the the variable.

```
template <typename T>
struct InfoHolder
{
    static const char** getName()
    {
        static const char* name;
        return &name;
    }
};

int main()
{
    *InfoHolder<int>::getName() = "This is an integer";
    *InfoHolder<MyClass>::getName() = "This is an MyClass";
    *InfoHolder<OtherClass>::getName() = "This is an OtherClass";
    cout << *InfoHolder<int>::getName() << endl;
    cout << *InfoHolder<MyClass>::getName() << endl;
    cout << *InfoHolder<OtherClass>::getName() << endl;
}
```